# Keycloak custom spi - custom transaction timeout

Tags: java, transactions, timeout, keycloak, keycloak-spi

I am trying to do a ***sync*** process via the *keycloak ImportSynchronization* interface. 
(wildlfy 18.0.1.Final)
it provides the following method to override:

```
    @Override
    public SynchronizationResult sync(
        final KeycloakSessionFactory sessionFactory,
        final String realmId,
        final UserStorageProviderModel model) {
    ...}
```

This sync process takes *much more time than our default transaction timeout* (300 sec = 5 min).

***I am aware of this possible opportunity:***

```
            <core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.tx.node.id:1}">
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment statistics-enabled="${wildfly.transactions.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"
                                     default-timeout="${env.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_SEC:300}"/>
            <object-store path="tx-object-store" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </subsystem>
```

***BUT this is not what I want, unfortunately.***

I ***don't want*** to increase the timeout for all of our processes, just for this one. Meaning I am searching for a custom transaction timeout solution. (something like @TransactionTimeout...)

---

I've tried the following

```
@Override
    public SynchronizationResult doCleanup(final KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory, final String realmId)  {
        final SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult = new SynchronizationResult();

        try {

            final RealmModel realmModel = this.getRealmModelInTx(realmId, keycloakSessionFactory);

            Thread.sleep(<more than tx timeout>);

            final int userEntityCountBeforeCleanup = this.getUserCountInTx(realmModel, keycloakSessionFactory);
...}
```

and ***in both methods, I created a new keycloakSession and a new transactionManager*** and ***closed*** them like here:

```
    private CleanupTransactionHandler createSession(final KeycloakSessionFactory  keycloakSessionFactory) {
        KeycloakTransactionManager transactionManager = null;
        final KeycloakSession keycloakSession = keycloakSessionFactory.create();

        log.tracef("KeycloakSession has been created [%s].", keycloakSession.hashCode());
        transactionManager = keycloakSession.getTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.begin();
        log.tracef("KeycloakTransactionManager's transaction has been begun [%s].", transactionManager.hashCode());
        return new CleanupTransactionHandler(keycloakSession,transactionManager);
    }

    private void closeSession(final KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        keycloakSession.close();
        log.tracef("KeycloakSession has been closed [%s].", keycloakSession.hashCode());
    }

    private void rollback(final KeycloakTransactionManager keycloakTransactionManager) {
        keycloakTransactionManager.rollback();
        log.tracef("KeycloakTransactionManager's transaction has been rolled back [%s].", keycloakTransactionManager.hashCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone wonders how this might be fixed in Keycloak 21.1.1++, here is what I did:

- enable quarkus config file

  - add `KC_QUARKUS_PROPERTIES_ENABLED=true` as env variable or `kc.quarkus-properties-enabled` flag
- make a `quarkus.properties` file, and add hte following:

```
quarkus.transaction-manager.default-transaction-timeout=PT6H
```

The `quarkus.properties` file must be copied to the `conf` folder in the Keycloak distribution.

Sources: tons of debugging :)

https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus

https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#configuring-the-transaction-timeout

Regarding the duration format:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own answer.

There is no possibility to customize the transaction timeout for this process, since ImportSynchronization.sync is called from `KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction`, that can only configured via default-timeout as mentioned above.